# Why this simple Facebook Connect button doesn't work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a simple facebook login page at:

http://bit.ly/Ims3U6

In the app settings:

```
App Domain: mysite.com
Address site: http://www.mysite.com
```

but it doesn't work... why ?

Comment: it's working and ask for some permissions also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you handle the tokens , do you save them somehow? 
(Save it or use cookies) IT's very important, because when the page returns back you need to compare the variables with  the original token .

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) is a  good documentation for fb authentication.

Anyway which sdk do you use?